# Patrón de diseño «State» (estado)

Tags: patrones-de-diseño, lenguaje-agnóstico

Procurando implementar el patrón de diseño de estados (*state*) sobre un objeto que tendrá estados definidos (estáticos), he topado con una duda.

De acuerdo con varios libros (y especialmente: [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) - *The GoF*) se detalla que la lógica deberá ser responsabilidad de los estados en lugar del contexto; brindado un enfoque polimorfo y de bajo acoplamiento.

Como analogía a un problema más sencillo, se me ocurrió el siguiente.

---

#### Problema

Realizar la simulación de un vehículo con los estados y acciones a continuación:

- Apagado:

  - Arrancar: enciende el motor.
- Encendido:

  - Avanzar: avanza el vehículo *x* cantidad de km.

```js
class CarState {
  constructor(ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
  }

  turnOff() {
    throw new Error('The car is already off.');
  }

  turnOn() {
    throw new Error('The car is already on.');
  }

  moveForward() {
    throw new Error('Forbidden operation.');
  }
}

class OffCarState extends CarState {
  turnOn() {  
    let state = new OnCarState(this.ctx);
    this.ctx.setState(state);
  }
}

class OnCarState extends CarState {
  turnOff() {
    let state = new OffCarState(this.ctx);
    this.ctx.setState(state);
  }

  moveForward() {
    this.ctx.km += 1;
    this.ctx.fuel -= 0.5;
    console.log('Avanzando 1km.');

    if (this.ctx.fuel < 0.5) {
      console.log('Sin combustible: apagando motor.');
    
      let state = new OffCarState(this.ctx);
      this.ctx.setState(state);
    }
  }
}

class Car {
  constructor() {
    this.fuel = 1;
    this.km = 0;
  
    this.state = new OffCarState(this);
  }

  turnOff() {
    this.state.turnOff();
  }

  turnOn() {
    this.state.turnOn();
  }

  moveForward() {
    this.state.moveForward();
  }
  
  setState(state) {
    let from = this.state.constructor.name,
         to = state.constructor.name;

    console.log(`State: ${from} -> ${to}`);
    this.state = state;
  }
  
  printStats() {
     let p  = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0],
      state = this.state instanceof OnCarState ? 'Encendido' : 'Apagado';
      
     p.innerText = `Estado: ${state}, Km: ${this.km}, Gas: ${this.fuel}.`;
  }

}

/**
 * Ejemplo en uso.
 */
let car = new Car();

let btnTurnOn  = document.getElementById('turn-on'),
    btnTurnOff = document.getElementById('turn-off'),
    btnMoveFwd = document.getElementById('move-fwd');

btnTurnOn.addEventListener('click', car.turnOn.bind(car));
btnTurnOff.addEventListener('click', car.turnOff.bind(car));
btnMoveFwd.addEventListener('click', car.moveForward.bind(car));

document.addEventListener('click', car.printStats.bind(car));
document.addEventListener('load', car.printStats.bind(car))
```

```html
<button id="turn-on">Encender</button>
<button id="turn-off">Apagar</button>
<button id="move-fwd">Avanzar</button>

<p>Tablero: <span></span></p>
```

La duda es: ¿lo adecuado es modificar las propiedades del contexto desde los estados?

En caso de que el objeto **Car** sea de un tercero (y por tanto no implementa *state*) ¿sería óptimo un esquema como el siguiente?

[image: Diagrama de clases - Patrón de diseño: estado]